# In Tensorflow, what is the difference between a tensor that has a type ending in _ref and a tensor that does not?

Tags: tensorflow

The docs say:

> In addition, variants of these types with the _ref suffix are defined
>   for reference-typed tensors.

What exactly does this mean? What are reference-typed tensors and how do they differ from standard ones?

Comment: if `variable.dtype` is `tf.float32_ref` then `tf.dtype.base_dtype` is `tf.float32`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A reference-typed tensor is **mutable**. The most common way to create a reference-typed tensor is to define a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable): defining a `tf.Variable` whose initial value has dtype `tf.float32` will create a reference-typed tensor with dtype `tf.float32_ref`. You can mutate a reference-typed tensor by passing it as the first argument to `tf.assign()`.

(Note that reference-typed tensors are something of an implementation detail in the present version of TensorFlow. We'd encourage you to use higher-level wrappers like `tf.Variable`, which may migrate to alternative representations for mutable state in the future.)

Comment: There isn't any documentation for `tf.assign()`, is it on purpose?

Comment: It's semi-on-purpose. We'd encourage using `tf.Variable.assign()` in preference to `tf.assign()`, but there are a few use cases (in particular, chained assignments) that only work with `tf.assign()`, so we haven't been able to remove it altogether.