# Find all variables that a tensorflow op depends upon

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way to find all variables that a given operation (usually a loss) depends upon?
I would like to use this to then pass this collection into `optimizer.minimize()` or `tf.gradients()` using various `set().intersection()` combinations.

So far I have found `op.op.inputs` and tried a simple BFS on that, but I never chance upon `Variable` objects as returned by `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)` or `slim.get_variables()`

There does seem to be a correspondence between corresponding 'Tensor.op._id`and`Variables.op._id` fields, but I'm not sure that's a something I should rely upon.

Or maybe I should't want to do this in the first place?
I *could* of course construct my disjoint sets of variables meticulously while building my graph, but then it would be easy to miss something if I change the model.

Comment: I've posted a related answer that provides a one-liner to print out the dependency graph here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56171327/4790871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for `tf.Variable.op`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#op) is not particularly clear, but it does refer to the crucial `tf.Operation` used in [the implementation of a `tf.Variable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42798537/3574081): any op that depends on a `tf.Variable` will be on a path from that operation. Since the `tf.Operation` object is hashable, you can use it as the key of a `dict` that maps `tf.Operation` objects to the corresponding `tf.Variable` object, and then perform the BFS as before:

```
op_to_var = {var.op: var for var in tf.trainable_variables()}

starting_op = ...
dependent_vars = []

queue = collections.deque()
queue.append(starting_op)

visited = set([starting_op])

while queue:
  op = queue.popleft()
  try:
    dependent_vars.append(op_to_var[op])
  except KeyError:
    # `op` is not a variable, so search its inputs (if any). 
    for op_input in op.inputs:
      if op_input.op not in visited:
        queue.append(op_input.op)
        visited.add(op_input.op)
```

Comment: there might be an issue with this looping infinitely... I tried this, and it hung. I added a `set` to track which `Op`s were already in the `queue`, and it returned immediately

Comment: You're quite right! The original code would fail if the graph contained a cycle. I've updated it to use a `visited` set.