# Cloning a network with tf.contrib.graph_editor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a function like this that builds a network.

```
def build_network(inputs):
  # Some arbitrary set of variables and ops here. For example...
  out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs, 123)
  (...)
  return out
```

Then I use it to build a network like this.

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(...)
outputs = build_network(inputs)
```

If I wanted to build more networks with identical structure but independent variables I'd just have to call *build_network* again under some other variable scope and, optionally, other inputs.

My question is: how can I do this if this *build_network* is no longer available, but the inputs and outputs of the original network are? In other words: how can I clone the entire subgraph from *outputs* all the way to *inputs* into another variable scope with its own independent set of variables but identical structure?

My understanding is that tf.contrib.graph_editor in general and graph_editor.copy in particular are precisely the tools I need to do these kind of things. However, I couldn't find any good example of their use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Responding myself, I have found what looks like a way to copy the subgraph.

```
from tensorflow.contrib import graph_editor as ge

# From the example above.
inputs = [tf.placeholder(...), ...]
outputs = build_network(inputs)

sgv = ge.make_view(ge.get_within_boundary_ops(
    tf.get_default_graph(),
    [t.op for t in outputs],
    [t.op for t in inputs]))

# This could be any new inputs. In this example I build new identical placeholders.
new_inputs = {p: tf.placeholder(dtype=p.dtype, shape=p.shape) for p in inputs}
new_sgv, info = ge.copy_with_input_replacements(sgv, new_inputs, dst_scope='copy')

new_inputs = [info.transformed(t) for t in inputs]
new_outputs = [info.transformed(t) for t in outputs]
```

However, now I'm facing a new problem when trying to use the network copy. The new variables in the copy are not initialized, and trying to run tf.global_variables_initializer() does not help.

The reason is that since the tf.Variable for these were never built, they are not part of the GlobalKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES collection. I can easily find the ops corresponding to these variables and their mapping between original and copy, but I cannot build a tf.Variable from that.

I found bit of a hacky workaround to do the initialization, but it only works for vars in a collection.

```
init_ops = []
for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES):
  if v.op in sgv.ops:
    init_ops.append(info.transformed(v.initializer))

...

session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer()] + init_ops)
```

Is there any better way to do this? Ideally one that allows creating tf.Variables for the copied vars to add them to the global vars collection. Or, if that weren't possible, at least a reliable way to get the initializer ops without having to find the tf.Variable objects of the original network.

Comment: Check my answer below for a more elegant solution for `tf.Variable`.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: this answer and the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45897756/4789373) are complementary to each other. Read [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45897756/4789373) first.

I've spent 4 hours today on this issue. This is one of the places where the ugliness of TensorFlow unfolds (and that's why you should use [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) if graph manipulation is your thing).

---

**The crucial point here is:** the [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) is NOT a graph element (more on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167134/whats-the-difference-between-tensor-and-variable-in-tensorflow/44167844)) but a wrapper around 3 ops: the `Assign` op, the `Read` op, and the `VariableV2` op which is essentially a `ref tensor` (more on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783909/internals-of-variable-in-tensorflow)). So, it is something you need to call explicitly in the TensorFlow Framework.

If we look closely at the `graph_editor`'s code, especially the [transform module](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/contrib/graph_editor/transform.py), we can see that it operates only on the `tf.Graph`, not touching anything from the TensorFlow Framework. So, the `graph_editor.copy` (and similar) methods **does not touch `tf.Variable` objects at all**. It only copies the tensors and ops that are building blocks of `tf.Variable`.

> Okay, then how do we solve this problem?

Suppose you have the following variable:

```python
var = tf.get_trainable_variables()[0]
print(var.to_proto())
# variable_name: "dense_1/kernel:0"
# initializer_name: "dense_1/kernel/Assign"
# snapshot_name: "dense_1/kernel/read:0"
# initial_value_name: "dense_1/random_uniform:0"
# trainable: true
```

You know that after `graph_editor.copy(...)`, your `dense_1` name scope is now `dense_1b`. Then, all you need is use `info.transformed(...)` to get the corresponding ops and tensors, and do the following:

```python
from tensorflow.core.framework import variable_pb2

var_def = variable_pb2.VariableDef()
var_def.variable_name = 'dense_1b/kernel:0'
var_def.initializer_name = "dense_1b/kernel/Assign"
var_def.snapshot_name = "dense_1b/kernel/read:0"
var_def.initial_value_name = "dense_1/random_uniform:0"
var_def.trainable = True
```

Now, I want to emphasize on the following part of [`tf.Variable` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable):

> `variable_def`: ... recreates the Variable object with its contents, referencing the variable's nodes in the graph, which must already exist. The graph is not changed.

So, the [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) constructor allows us to create a Variable wrapper **on top of existing** graph elements. That's exactly what we need:

```python
cloned_var = tf.Variable(variable_def=var_def)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, cloned_var)
```

**Solved!**

---

I kept this answer as simple and specific as possible to show the underlying mechanics of `tf.Variables`. You can now easily implement the code for more general case to make new variables automatically.

**PS: I hate TensorFlow!**

Comment: In PyTorch, if `build_network` is no longer available, you would not be able to do that at all, or would you? The whole point in PyTorch would be that you always *must* call `build_network` again and again. But you could just do the same also in TensorFlow?