# How to apply custom gradient: error with type conversion

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am implementing DDPG. I need to calculate a custom gradient (the gradient of the weights of the actor which maximizes the output of the critic) and then apply it with an optimizer. However, for some reason I get a mysterious type error when I try running it.

I tried looking at other tutorials and searching on stack overflow but can't find how to fix the error.

This is an example code which gets the error (the actual computation is more complicated but gets an answer of the same form):

```
actor = Sequential()
actor.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(6,)))
# actor_inputs is randomly sampled
sess = K.get_session()
grad_op = K.gradients(actor.output, actor.trainable_weights)
grads = sess.run(grad_op, feed_dict={actor.input: actor_inputs})
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4)
opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, actor.trainable_weights))
```

The gradient that this computes seems correct. I expected the optimizer to apply it to the network but I get the following error in the `apply_gradients` call:

```
Tensor conversion requested dtype float32_ref for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("Adam_24/dense_95/kernel/m/Initializer/zeros:0", shape=(6, 2), dtype=float32)'
```

Here is the result of some test prints of relevant data:

`print(actor_inputs)`:

```
[[-0.43979521  0.         -1.28554755  0.          0.94703663 -0.32112555]]
```

`print(grad_op)`:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_2/dense_95/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1:0' shape=(6, 2) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradients_2/dense_95/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32>]
```

`print(grads)`:

```
[array([[ 3.003665  ,  3.003665  ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [-2.2157073 , -2.2157073 ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [-0.8517535 , -0.8517535 ],
       [ 0.52394277,  0.52394277]], dtype=float32), array([1., 1.], dtype=float32)]
```

`print(actor.trainable_weights)`:

```
[<tf.Variable 'dense_95/kernel:0' shape=(6, 2) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'dense_95/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggest `apply_gradients` expects a `float32_ref` and not a `float32` for grads.

There probably are multiple ways to get around this with explicit conversions, but assigning `grads` or `grad_op` to a [tf.Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) might solve the issue.

Doing so should do the convertion, but you can specify `dtype=float32_ref` when assigning the `tf.Variable` to be sure.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958706/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-a-tensor-that-has-a-type-ending-in) is a post about the difference between the two.

Comment: Can you give a specific code snipet how to do this? I am quite new to tf.